# Error Compilation with angular-cli + angular material

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-material2

i'm using **angular metirials** with **angular-cli** by using [this guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-angular-material) and dealing with this error 
 when runing the ng serve command:
**Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts**

*I assume it has problem with my packages versions but i failed to fix it*

**my package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "@angular2-material/button": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-3",
    "@angular2-material/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

**NOTES**

- I imported the MetirialModule to the app.module.ts as i should
- i imported the following links to the style.css
- '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.css';
      '~https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';

My error:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried different approach to fix this issue and it worked for me:

1. i **updated the angular-cli version** using [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update) guide

   Note: not sure if its a must step but it fixed issues for me
2. **created new app using the new cli version**
3. **used [this](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) guide to install the materials package**

Answer (score 1):

You need "typescript": "2.1.0" in your `package.json` `dev-dependencies`

Comment: did you try updating to typescript 2.2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Update your **Typescript** to a latest version, use this command:

```
npm install -g typescript@latest
```

Now run the application again with 'ng serve'.
It should work.

If it doesnt work follow https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update
and install @angular/material again.
You may get this error that " Cannot find module '@angular/animations'". In this case use below cmd:

```
npm install @angular/animations
```